# A basic doubt on limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) =L$. Does this imply that there exist a neighbourhood around $c$ such that $|f(x)| \leq |L|$.

Comment: No, of course. Consider any strictly increasing (or decreasing) function.

Comment: The term "doubt" in Indian English, becomes "question" in US English.

Comment: Try $f(x)=x$ and $c=0$.

Answer (score 4):

No, but for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some neighbourhood of $c$ such that $|f(x)| \le L+\epsilon$.

Comment: True, but there is a difference between $\forall$ and $\exists$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Think $$\lim_{x\to0}x^2=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

No.  Consider the function $f(x) = x^2$.  You have $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$, but there is no open neighborhood of $0$ within which $f(x)\le 0$.